# Using python list to generate output

Tags: python-3.x

My input is list=[1,2,3,4] so I want output like using python list, 
Output list=[10,20,30].

How to make program on python using List method

Comment: Take the first 3 elements and multiply them by 10.

Comment: Why do you drop 4? or is it always last element in the list that you drop? Explain your use case here.

Comment: that is okay but i want 3  values output only like [10,20,30]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> list = [1, 2, 3, 4]    
>>> print([x*10 for x in list])
[10, 20, 30, 40]
```